# REQUEST: WWII Airplane Bys

Tags: request, sfx, airplane

I need some extremely close, exciting P-51 or similar deep, throaty, exciting airplane bys. Preferably extremely close, high quality recordings with lots of punchy low-end.

Willing to trade or buy.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: @Jay Thanks for correcting. I googled it before asking, and it turns out that's an extremely common mistake.

Answer (score 4):

This [boutique library](http://www.johnleonard.co.uk/immersive.html) from John Leonard called "sounds of flight" might do the trick. The price is certainly right...

Comment: WOW How did I not find this in my searches? Thanks a lot!!